# Some users are redirected to cpanel cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi while other don't

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, apache2, vps, linux

I have a website which used to be hosted on a managed Bluehost plan that includes a cPanel by default. for some non-technical reasons, I've decided to move the website from Bluehost to an unmanaged Linode VPS server and added a cPanel licence to it then I moved the website to that server after doing all the necessary setups.

Some users from different countries see cPanel's `cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` sorry page while the rest of the users do not see this problem at all.

I personally have the website working when I access it via one ISP and not working with the other. I thought this might be only me and my bad second ISP but I made sure it's not the case as people from other places with other ISPs are facing the same problem too!

what I've tried already?

1. I've checked the IP address in WHM and made sure it has the right value
2. I've checked that the .htaccess file is not causing that redirect
3. I've checked that it's not because of a meta tag like this
4. Also made sure that it's not the hosts file

I mean even without all these tries above if it was something from the server it simply won't work at all with anyone. the fact that this is working with some users and not working with others (both have no caches on their PCs or browsers) means only that something wrong between the server and the user's devices happens but I can't seem to be able to figure it out or solve it.

PS: the website has been moved to that new server for weeks so far.

Answer (score 1):

Consider rechecking the DNS records of you domian. The DNS records should point towards your new Linode VPS server properly. Check whether your DNS records have been propagated properly accross the globe using dnschecker or other tools.

If you find an issue with DNS not being propagated then there might be a fair chance that the issue is that your DNS is not updated properly.

Moving to a faster DNS service like cloudflare would also be advantageous. You only need to update the new NS records in your domain, which are provided by cloudflare when you add a website in your account